# How do I delete blank panels from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2. It has acquired a couple of blank panels (see screenshots) that appear in every perspective. I would like to delete them, but do not know how. Hitting either Minimize or maximize makes them take more space. Restarting Eclipse doesn't change them.

Thanks everyone

[image: See grey blank panels in lower-right in Java Browsing perspective]

[image: See grey blank panels on right in Java Type Hierarchy perspective]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't know if this was ever solved, but I just had an identical similar issue with the Eclipse-based Aptana Studio 3, and was able to solve it without an uninstall/reinstall or having to shift everything to a new workspace.

I finally solved it by right clicking each available perspective in the upper right, and closing them all: [image: close_every_perspective],

until all perspectives are closed and you see a screen as shown below: [image: no_perspectives_view].

At this point you should reopen a perspective and for me, at least, that worked. Hope it works for you and others that are having this issue.

Comment: +1 for the solution that fixed me. If you get a perspective that is buggered up in this manner, right click on the perspective name and close it. When you re-add it, it will be in its default state again, eliminating the rogue panel(s).

Comment: If you want a quick workaround, minimize the panel then drag it to the bottom right corner of the Eclipse window. It's unobtrusive there.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on panel's top bar(near minimize button) and select **Close**.

If you want more space for writing code, double click file tab(file name) and it will minimize all panels and expand your code writing area. Double click it again to go back to original position.

Comment: Thanks Naveed, but right-clicking the top bar of the gray panel doesn't produce a menu. It does produce a menu (containing Close) for the other panels. I think we're dealing with a bug, and need a work-around.

Comment: Yes. May be it is a bug. Try re-installing eclipse.

Comment: Is there an easy way to reinstall Eclipse without reinstalling all my plugins? Obviously, I can point Eclipse to my existing workspace. Is there an automated way to handle the rest of the configuration and customization? Can I also simply copy entries from the directories in the old installation to directories in the new one? Thanks Arthur

Comment: I did not try this.... I don't think it is easy task to keep the plugins and re-install eclipse. May be I am wrong. You have to research.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently and I did this

```
Window > Perspective > Close all Perspective > Save
```

Then Go to Perspective again choose Other and choose Java(Default). After that manually close every perspective that you don't want.

Finally go to `Windows > Show View > Console`