# How can I re-install Eclipse without losing customization?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Since I need to work-around [an Eclipse bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319662/how-do-i-delete-blank-panels-from-eclipse) I need to re-install it. Is there an easy way that keeps my customization, such as plug-ins and projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your projects are stored separately from Eclipse.

However, you would lose your plug-ins.  That's why the first thing you should do after you unpack Eclipse and load all of your plugins is zip up your customized Eclipse.  Then, when you re-unpack your customized Eclipse, you have all your plugins.